# When using integrated_address, does the sender HAVE to include the random payment ID?

Tags: integrated-address

Will a transaction still execute successfully if the sender does not include the random payment ID that is given when integrated_address is used by the receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network will absolutely accept it just fine; it doesn't know if a Tx is supposed to have a payment ID or not.

However, if a receiver is giving you an integrated address, they are probably expecting to receive a payment with that ID attached. If that ID isn't included, the transaction might not be properly recognized by them.